# Importing 3d objects from blender in unity results in distortion

Tags: unity

We created a 3d object (molecule of HCL) in blender with its bonds, but when we imported them in unity, the bonds position was displaced from its original.
As shown in images below

[image: In unity]
[image: In blender]

Comment: This is a question about Unity, not Blender.

Comment: I don't get about your "bonds", as I can see there is no bond in unity image... Or what do you mean by "displaced"?

Comment: Bonds are present in unity as well, but the problem is they all have displaced inside the green atom, they have displaced from their position as seen in unity